# Mercurial Eclipse Plugin

Tags: eclipse, mercurial, eclipse-plugin

Where can I find a good Eclipse Mercurial Plugin?

Comment: Are you asking for opinions on specific plugin(s)? I easily found one or via Google and was wondering whether you had seen that one yet.

Answer (score 206, accepted):

**[MercurialEclipse](https://bitbucket.org/mercurialeclipse/main/)**

Update site: https://bitbucket.org/mercurialeclipse/update-site/raw/default/

[Installation manual](https://bitbucket.org/mercurialeclipse/main/wiki/Installation%20and%20Configuration)

As stated below (in comments) the name is MercurialEclipse.  The name HgEclipse was a fork that Intland did and was later "merged" back again with MercurialEclipse, which moved around a bit between the current site, Google code and javaforge.com.

Comment: This plugin is the successor to the mercurialeclipse plugin mentioned at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1629058/mercurial-eclipse-plugin/1629086#1629086.

Comment: Its disappointing that you need to sign up at java forge in order to download this plugin

Comment: Check here instead: http://andrei.gmxhome.de/mercurialeclipse/index.html No registration required. The update site URL is at the bottom of the page. But read the whole thing anyway.

Comment: Registration is NOT required anymore.

Comment: **HgEclipse** changed name to **MercurialEclipse**. *You might have already heard that HgEclipse (the plugin currently installed in your Eclipse) and the original MercurialEclipse project will reunite with the 1.6.0 release. (Details to be announced in May 2010.)* - http://www.javaforge.com/wiki/86753

Comment: Guys, but where to download the plugin itself?! (to install it in offline)

Comment: @zerkms If you are going to download it, why don't you do it using Eclipse's pluging manager? The url is http://cbes.javaforge.com/update

Comment: @glarrain: ? It just installs mercurial eclipse. What I need is just a zipped site update to install it on the machine without internet.

Comment: The plugin does not work. Several operations I have attempted resulted in "null argument" exceptions. Had to uninstall it in 5 minutes.

Comment: I had to wait for 3 minutes to get past eclipse "Pending..."

Comment: @intland: On the MercurialEclipse page as of Nov 2012 "To download or upgrade MercurialEclipse, please sign up at JavaForge first."

Comment: The cbes update URL contains an old version (as of writing, 2.0.0, while the official site contains 2.1.1)

Comment: Update site has changed:
https://bitbucket.org/mercurialeclipse/update-site/raw/default/

You can also use the installation manual:
https://bitbucket.org/mercurialeclipse/main/wiki/Installation%20and%20Configuration

Comment: @HanochGiner: That new update site seems to be recognised, but once I start trying to install the plugin from there, I get an error: `Artifact not found: http://mercurialeclipse.eclipselabs.org.codespot.com/files/com.vectrace.MercurialEclipse_2.1.0.201304290948.jar`. I'm hoping that's just temporary...

Comment: If anyone encounters the same error, it seems that the "experimental" version 2.2 works, while the "stable" version 2.1 has the artifact not found problem.

Comment: Bitbucket is dead, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/63936148/491245 for the current (as 2023) site.

Answer (score 7):

Vectrace is dead. They say you need to go to javaforge ( http://cbes.javaforge.com/update ).
WARNING: plugin on javaforge is unsigned and cannot be verified.

Comment: Prorper link is now vectrace.com/projects/mercurialeclipse but its only a redirect to the new proper project place bitbucket.org/mercurialeclipse/main

Answer (score 6):

Now that **Bitbucket is dead**, the new location of *MercurialEclipse* is:

- https://foss.heptapod.net/mercurial/mercurialeclipse/-/wikis/home

And the update site is:

- https://foss.heptapod.net/mercurial/mercurialeclipse-updatesite/-/raw/branch/default/p2

Comment: Here I am, advocating Eclipse and Mercurial within my company and both are just torpedoing my efforts. If this isn't fixed soon, IntelliJ and Git are just going to run away with this

Answer (score 3):

**Update 2017-May-6:** the below is no longer applicable, the accepted answer  has been updated.

I think the accepted answer is now outdated, what's available in the 'Market Place' does not work when adding a repository with latest Java 1.8 x64 ([Issue #60](https://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/mercurialeclipse/issues/detail?id=60&thanks=60&ts=1433181751)) - was hoping installing a the snapshot would help but it did not.

```
http://mercurialeclipse.eclipselabs.org.codespot.com/hg.wiki/update_site/snapshots
    MercurialEclipse    2.1.1.201401121312
```

Here are the other versions found:

```
http://mercurialeclipse.eclipselabs.org.codespot.com/hg.wiki/update_site/stable
    MercurialEclipse    2.1.0.201304290948

http://hge.javaforge.com/mercurialeclipse-snapshots
    MercurialEclipse    1.9.0.201106191824
```

Answer (score -2):

Here is the web-site: http://www.vectrace.com/mercurialeclipse/
The update site is: http://www.vectrace.com/eclipse-update/

Comment: Prorper link is now http://www.vectrace.com/projects/mercurialeclipse but its only a redirect to the new proper project place https://bitbucket.org/mercurialeclipse/main/