# How to use Mercurial in side Eclipse Helios (3.6)

Tags: mercurial, eclipse-plugin, mercurialeclipse

I am using Eclipse Helios (3.6). I want to use Mercurial for version management of the program. I have take the help of the below link to find out the plugin but not got any success:

- [Mercurial Eclipse Plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1629058/mercurial-eclipse-plugin)

Can any one please help to install Mercurial plugins inside my Eclipse and I also don't know how to use also. I have gone through the video also but not clear.

- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9OBg6Zv0Tns

My question is that I want to use Mercurial in my project for version control. I know what Mercurial is, but don't know how to use it.

**I want to know what is the initial setup that I have do if I want to use Mercurial set up in my project.**

When I am trying to add new software It is giving me following error.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the 'Duplicate Location' error message in your screenshot would indicate that there is already an update site setup for that URL.

In the screen before doing the 'add repository' look at the list of current update sites and you may find one for Mercurial already. Make sure it is selected and a list of all the features for that update site will be listed for you. Then you can select the MercurialEclipse and MercurialBinaries features and install then in Eclipse

Answer (score 0):

The Mercurial Eclipse homepage is here: http://javaforge.com/project/HGE.

They have [installation instructions](http://javaforge.com/project/HGE#download) there:

> [...] you can get the plugin easily using the Eclipse Update Manager, just click Help → Software Updates in Eclipse. The Eclipse Update Site for MercurialEclipse is available at this URL:
>
> ```
> http://cbes.javaforge.com/update
> ```
>
> If you are not familiar with getting new software and updates to Eclipse, please read [this article](http://help.eclipse.org/help33/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/tasks/tasks-34.htm).

Comment: Thanks Martin for your reply. Inside Help their is no option called software Updates. Their is other option is "Install New Software". I have put the above Link their but it is giving the error please see the screen shot. I will edit my question and put screen shot their please check.