# Getting the whole project on Google Code

Tags: android, google-code

I'm really new to this and I don't have any idea how to do this: how do you get the whole source code from [this project](http://code.google.com/p/andenginelivewallpaperextensionexample/source/browse/#hg/src/org/anddev/wallpaper/live/cigarette) ?

Please tell me because i can't find the download button. I go to the download tab and it's not there.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click the "Checkout" link under the "Source" tab in the menu.

There, you'll get a Mercurial command you can execute in your shell:

```
hg clone https://code.google.com/p/andenginelivewallpaperextensionexample/
```

#### See also:

- [Mercurial Beginner's Guides](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/BeginnersGuides)
- [Where can I find a good Eclipse Mercurial Plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1629058/mercurial-eclipse-plugin)

Comment: Ive never used mercurial before. ahm can u tell me how to set it up? is it on eclipse?

Comment: @Tifa: Take a look at the related links I provided.

Comment: Thank you soooooo much. I downloaded it.. It works haha.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Click on the *source* tab

Here is the whole command that you can use to download the source of the project:

```
hg clone https://code.google.com/p/andenginelivewallpaperextensionexample/
```

hg is a tool that comes with Mercurial, you need `Mercurial` to get that repository.